# Windows - Python, check if program is open and if it is, open it from taskbar?

Tags: python, google-chrome, pyautogui

I have a program that uses PyAutoGui to open up Google Chrome and go to the website I want it to, however it opens up a new Chrome every time, is there a way I could make it check if it is open and if it is just click it in the taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

Not with pyautogui by itself.

You could use [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) as a cross platform way to find out if Chrome is running. If you're on Windows, you could use the win32api.

Comment: Does win32api work with 64bit system and does it support Python 3.5?